# Why is console telling me not defined?

Tags: jquery

```
$(".bVid").on("click",function(){
        $(".vidBeginner").slideDown(1000);
});
```

On that JS code above, Chrome console keeps telling me the first "$" is not defined. There is a class in my html file called "bVid" and it's attached to a button. I also have it in my css file that's also attached to the html file in the header. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is jQuery included? Did you put this code on `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery script?

Comment: possible duplicate [jquery-is-not-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Yes I included the jQuery script at the bottom of the body in the html file.

Comment: Sorry it was a duplicate. Thanks Bijoy. Yes it was that my seperate js file was not after jquery. My bad all. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:

```
    (function($){ 
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".bVid").on("click",function(){
              $(".vidBeginner").slideDown(1000);
           }); 
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Make sure you have included the jquery cdn in script tags before calling this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your jquery above your script then you need to use `$(document).ready(function ()` function like given below

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".bVid").on("click",function(){
        $(".vidBeginner").slideDown(1000);
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```